# How to display AJAX response value in column format individual?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am getting only 3 users value from PHP using AJAX and that value I have to display in column format. I have tried below code but It is not displaying.
I am getting output like all the first name is displaying vertically then after displaying the last name vertically.

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search-button').click(function(){
            $.ajax( {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'includes/process.php',
                data: $('#search-form').serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {                     
                    for(data in response)
                    {
                    $('#response_profile_pic').append("<img src='images/profile/" + response[data].profile_pic + "' alt='' />");
                    $('#response_fName').append("<li>" + response[data].fName +"</li>");
                    $('#response_lName').append("<li>" + response[data].lName + "</li>"); 
                    }
                    $('#open_compare_popup').show();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**PHP**

```
    <div class="box-set"> 
        <ul class="point_compare">
            <span id="response_profile_pic"></span>
            <label>First Name</label><h2 id="response_fName"></h2>
            <label>Last Name</label><span id="response_lName"></span>
        </ul>
</div>
```

**Process.php**

```
$_SESSION['compare_user']=$_POST['compare_id'];//coming from html
$sql_compare='SELECT * FROM request WHERE Id IN (' .( is_array( $_SESSION['compare_user'] ) ? implode( ',', $_SESSION['compare_user'] ) : $_SESSION['compare_user'] ).')';
//echo $sql_compare;
//die();
$compare_records = array();
    $compare_query=$conn->query($sql_compare);
    if ($compare_query->num_rows > 0) {
    while($userdata12=$compare_query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        $compare_records[]=$userdata12;
        //echo $compare_pic;
    }
}
echo json_encode($compare_records);exit();
```

Comment: Does response return an array or an object? It returns an array, yes? Are you trying to access an array found within `response.data` ?

Comment: Yes, It returns the object. I just want to repeat the div every time depending upload the array count

Comment: My solution should help but I'm not sure of the exact structure of the `response` - if you provide that, I can confirm / modify my code to work.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: based on your HTML, here's how I would do it.

```
success: function(response) {
    let repeatableDiv = "";

    response.data.forEach(val => {
    repeatableDiv += "<div class='box-set'> <span class='compare_userpic' id='response_profile_pic'><img src='images/profile/" + val.profile_pic + "' alt='' /></span>
    <ul class='point_compare'>
      <li>
        <h2>" + val.fName + "</h2>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>" + val.lName + "</h3>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>"      
  })

  $(".compare_result").innerHTML = repeatableDiv
```

Then clean out all of the HTML that you commented out, and it should work.

Comment: Hope you checked my HTML code. I have commented the line. I have to display all the output there.

Comment: I have to display each record separately inside that HTML code which I commented for information.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my response - try this and let me know what happens.

Comment: It's not taking any action. I mean no output

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
success: function(response) {
  $.each(response, function (i, item) {
    var fname= response[i]['fname'];
    var fname1= response['data'][0]['fname'];
    var fname2= response['data']['fname'];
    alert (fname);
    alert (fname1);
    alert (fname2);
  });
}
```

Comment: I have to repeat my HTML div which is commented in the code. Please check my HTML code

Answer (score 0):

It must be work. Do it:

```
<div id="container"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search-button').click(function(){
            $.ajax( {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'includes/process.php',
                data: $('#search-form').serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {                     

                    var container = document.getElementById('container');

                    for (key in response){
                        var div=document.createElement('div');
                        var img=document.createElement('img');
                        var flab=document.createElement('label');
                        var llab=document.createElement('label');
                        var fcaption=document.createElement('h2');
                        var lcaption=document.createElement('h2');

                        img.setAttribute('src','images/profile/' + response[data].profile_pic);    
                        img.setAttribute('alt','');    
                        flab.innerText='First Name';    
                        llab.innerText='Last Name';    
                        fcaption.innerText=response[key].fName
                        lcaption.innerText=response[key].lName

                        div.appendChild(img);
                        div.appendChild(flab);
                        div.appendChild(fcaption);
                        div.appendChild(llab);
                        div.appendChild(lcaption);

                        container.appendChild(div);
                    }    
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.aimprogman, Incase I have to add the same class or id for CSS then How can I add it?

Comment: @Hybreeder with  flab.setAttribute('class','label-style'); or flab.setAttribute('id','label-selector');

Comment: Is there any other option to solve this issue? Because I have more than 8 columns. What say?

Comment: And CSS is also too big

Comment: Did I understand you correctly? You can do it in css: #container > label  { color: white}

Comment: It is very hard to handle above code. Because now I have to add <center class="margin-20"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myfunction(<?php echo $userdata['Id']; ?>, <?php echo $cat_id; ?>, <?php echo $type; ?>)" >click</a></center>

Comment: and I am not able to do this also.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `JSON.parse();` in your response to resolve this issue

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search-button').click(function(){
        $.ajax( {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'includes/process.php',
            data: $('#search-form').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {                     
                response = JSON.parse(response);
                for(data in response) {
                    $('#response_profile_pic').append("<img src='images/profile/" + response[data].profile_pic + "' alt='' />");
                    $('#response_fName').append("<li>" + response[data].fName +"</li>");
                    $('#response_lName').append("<li>" + response[data].lName + "</li>"); 
                }
                $('#open_compare_popup').show();
            }
        });
    });
});

<div class="box-set"> 
    <ul class="point_compare">
        <span id="response_profile_pic"></span>
        <label>First Name</label><h2 id="response_fName"></h2>
        <label>Last Name</label><span id="response_lName"></span>
    </ul>
</div>

$compare_records = array();
$compare_query=$conn->query($sql_compare);

if ($compare_query->num_rows > 0) {
    $outp = array();
    $outp = $compare_query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($outp);
}

exit();
```

Comment: Let me try this also

Comment: Sorry Mr.Super User, When I am adding response = JSON.parse(response); then nothing is happing evening I tried to use alert inside for that also not displaying.

Comment: @Hybreeder can you share what data is coming in `response`

Comment: I upload My process code. I was getting output proper but not in proper format before using response = JSON.parse(response);

Comment: @Hybreeder I've updated my answer. You can update your php code with my answer.

Comment: You mean I have to change some code in PHP? I changed it but my first process is not working until and unless I will not get the idea that your code is working or not. because I am using the same query for both

Comment: can you share working fiddle or codepen, so i can debug your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153251/discussion-between-hybreeder-and-super-user).